# why beautifulsoup parser load xml file very slower than lxml even when set features to "lxml"?

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup, lxml

I had an question.
I have a 35000 lines xml file that want to parse it and search through it. I decide to use beautifulsoup for this purpose but the problem is that when I use Beautifulsoup parser it take long time to parse it even when use lxml as features. I read other related question and in one of answer someone was suggested to install cchardet module to speed up decoding procedure but that didn't have any effect either. However, when I use the lxml module, the parsing speed is much higher and because I use Raspberry Pi, this time difference is very big for me.

Do you have any other suggestions for me? Should I rewrite my code using lxml?

```
import time
import cchardet
from lxml import etree
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

tic = time.time()
with open("tree.xml","r") as f:
    tree = etree.parse(f)
    toc = time.time()
    print(f"etree parser Time: {toc - tic} Sec")

tic = time.time()
with open("tree.xml","r") as f:
    tree = BeautifulSoup(f, features="xml")
    toc = time.time()
    print(f"soup parser Time: {toc - tic} Sec")

>
etree parser Time: 0.4 Sec
soup parser Time: 8.9 Sec
```

Comment: Please quantify! Are we talking about it being 10 times slower or 10% slower?

Comment: What kind of feature does BeautifulSoup offer that lxml doesn't have. What other features other than building the tree do you need and is the BeautifulSoup code for that easier to write and/or performing better than the lxml code?

Comment: @MichaelKay, quantification is given: 0.4 secs (lxml etree) vs 8.9 secs (BeautifulSoup tree)

Comment: I came across this same issue in my app. I use `features="lxml-xml"` for BS4 but it still is not faster. Parsing a large sitemap takes 2.596s with BS4 and 0.27s with lxml.etree.